# authlogic with_scope not working on Rails 3 for multi account application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

After updating to rails 3 authlogic does not work so i am using the gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'

This works for the standard setup but i have a multi account setup and i used with_scope before so a user can only login to their account / subdomain and not any account / subdomain.

This code in my application controller was working before but not now as uses the old find and not the new arel syntax.

```
def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    UserSession.with_scope(:account_id => account_id) do
      @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end
end
```

Has any on managed to update this for rails 3 or found a fix ?

Please help !

Best regards
Richard

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Apparently, authlogic is kind of broken when it comes to with_scope.
Check this for details, it may also help you: http://groups.google.com/group/authlogic/browse_thread/thread/41c8d2fc82e1b69c

Are you using `authenticates_many`? I had a similar problem just now (my model that identifies the account/subdomain is called `Website`, and I have a before filter that sets `@website`). To fix it, I did the following:

I added the `:find_options => { :limit => 1 }` to the `authenticates_many`

```
class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_many :user_sessions, :find_options => { :limit => 1 }
```

My user model has the usual `validations_scope`:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.validations_scope = :website_id
end
```

And my `current_user_session` method became the following:

```
def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = @website.user_sessions.find
end
```

Hope it helps.